# Why Function.prototype.bind() "removes" custom properties from function?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to understand why `.bind()` removes custom property from the function.
What actually happens when I change context of the function that "removes" `_$something` method?

```
function xxx(){
//do nothing
}
xxx._$something = 'something';
document.getElementById('id1').innerText = xxx._$something;
//'something'

var functions = [];

functions.push(xxx);
document.getElementById('id2').innerText = functions[0]._$something;
//'something'

functions.push(xxx.bind({}));
document.getElementById('id3').innerText = functions[1]._$something;
//'undefined'

console.log(functions[1]); //logs xxx
```

[**JS fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/1h9yswL5/1/)

Comment: `bind()` returns a new function. Why would it have any properties on it?

Comment: if bind returns a copy of an object (function) I would expect it to have the same properties...

Comment: It doesn't return a copy of an object. That's not the goal.

Comment: @LJWadowski `bind` does not copy the function, it wraps it. `The bind() function creates a new bound function (BF). A BF is an exotic function object (term from ECMAScript 6)  that wraps the original function object. Calling a BF generally results in the execution of its wrapped function.` From the MDN

Comment: @LJWadowski, why are you adding properties to a function? What are you trying to build?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`bind` doesn't remove anything, it returns a **new** function.

From [the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind):

> The bind() method creates a new function that, when called, has its
>   this keyword set to the provided value, with a given sequence of
>   arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called.

To make it more obvious:

```
var f2 = f1.bind(obj);
```

is roughly equivalent to

```
var f2 = (function(f, v){
  return function(){
      return f.apply(v, arguments);
  }
})(f1, obj);
```

In both cases the original function isn't copied but *wrapped*.

Comment: If it returns new function, shouldn't it be a copy which has the same methods?

Comment: @LJWadowski It's not specified the properties should be copied and it would rarely be useful anyway. For example you wouldn't want the name to be the same (in fact it's usually built from the original name, like "bound xxx")

Comment: _$something is a property of your original method (which is an object actually). The _$something property doesn't get copied to the new returned function.